# How do i undo things in my Ubuntu 22.04LTS, GNOME Version 42.0 . Ctr + Z, Ctr + Y is not working?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

I just installed my Ubuntu not more than 5 days ago, i learned quite a bit and got used to it before i was using windows. Ubuntu keyboard shortcuts are lot different than windows. I can't find any solution to this problem anywhere, so how can i undo things in terminal is there another shortcut?

Comment: What do you want to undo exactly? Did you run some command and you want to undo the changes it made? That can't be done - you can't undo an arbitrary command. Or did you want to undo some changes you made while editing a command line?

Comment: Yeah i want to undo changes when i write a line in command line like if i delete a word can i recover by shortcut key in command line?

Comment: Ah. Try `Ctrl-_` (Ctrl and and underscore, but since underscore is the same key as minus/hyphen, Ctrl-minus)

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> keyboard shortcut will undo the previous terminal action such as pasting text or typing a string of characters.